# SQL Server Convert row to column

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking a way to convert rows to columns in SQL server, I've tried pivot but still haven't got the results I want.

Sample table

```
----------------------------------------
|  Code  |  Value  |  Status  |  Desc  |
----------------------------------------
| 000010 |    2    |   Trx1   |  X001  |
| 000010 |    1    |   Trx2   |  X001  |
| 000010 |    2    |   Trx1   |  X002  |
| 000010 |    2    |   Trx2   |  X002  |
| 000010 |    1    |   Trx1   |  X003  |
| 000010 |    1    |   Trx2   |  X003  |
```

From that table, I want to get result like

```
----------------------------------------
|  Code  | Status1 | Status2  |  Desc  |
----------------------------------------
| 000010 |    2    |     1    |  X001  |
| 000010 |    2    |     2    |  X002  |
| 000010 |    1    |     1    |  X003  |
```

How can i built result like that?

**Already found result I want by myself, thank you**

**Thank You**

Comment: Please provide some more info: where is "Trx1" and "Trx2" in your expected result? What are the grouping criteria? And what (especially which pivot) have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry guys, I already found the answer with pivot
I miss something on my query before

Comment: @ian tried with case statement please check once

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Code] int, [Value] int, [Status] varchar(4), [Desc] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Code], [Value], [Status], [Desc])
VALUES
    (000010, 2, 'Trx1', 'X001'),
    (000010, 1, 'Trx2', 'X001'),
    (000010, 2, 'Trx1', 'X002'),
    (000010, 2, 'Trx2', 'X002'),
    (000010, 1, 'Trx1', 'X003'),
    (000010, 1, 'Trx2', 'X003')
;
  SELECT FORMAT([Code],'000000')[Code] ,MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS]='Trx1' THEN [Value] END) AS [Value1] ,
              MAX(CASE WHEN [STATUS]='Trx2' THEN [Value] END) AS [Value2],[Desc]
FROM #Table1
GROUP BY [Code],[Desc]
```

OUTPUT

```
Code    Value1  Value2   Desc
10        2       1      X001
10        2       2      X002
10        1       1      X003
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you actually want to use PIVOT for this.

Here's a code snippet:

```sql
-- Using a table variable just for demonstration purposes
declare @Table table (Code varchar(6), Value int, [Status] varchar(30), [Desc] varchar(4));

-- Sample data
insert into @Table (Code, Value, [Status], [Desc]) values
 ('000010', 2, 'Trx1', 'X001')
,('000010', 1, 'Trx2', 'X001')
,('000010', 2, 'Trx1', 'X002')
,('000010', 2, 'Trx2', 'X002')
,('000010', 1, 'Trx1', 'X003')
,('000010', 1, 'Trx2', 'X003')
;

-- The pivot query
select Code, Status1, Status2, [Desc]
from 
(
select Code, [Desc], Value,
concat('Status', row_number() over (partition by Code, [Desc] order by [Status])) as Col
from @Table
) as src
pivot
( 
max([Value])
for Col in ([Status1], [Status2])
) as pvt
order by Code, [Desc];
```

Basically, row_number is used to generate the column names to pivot on.

Comment: Could just use `REPLACE()` to turn `'Trx'` into `'Status'`?

Comment: @MatBailie Just based on the sample data from the question, then sure.  It would generate the same column names.  But it's just sample data. In his actual data those Status values will probably look different.

Comment: If that's the case then not even `ROW_NUMBER()` is necessarily safe.  `TrxUno`, `TrxDos` would trip that up...

Comment: @MatBailie Nope, the row_number orders them alphabetically, so you still get a 1 and 2. Ok, I guess that TrxUno would be 2 then.  But if there are only 2 Statusses for all the Codes  (probably not in the real data) then I wouldn't use REPLACE for that. I'd rather just PIVOT on those values `for [Status] in ([Trx1],[Trx2])`, and then give them aliases in the outer query.